# Wrong Number of Arguments Error with ActiveRecord New

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arguments, activemodel

I have a ActiveRecord::Base subclass. When I create a new instance I'm getting an argument error:

```
ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Here is my code:

```
class Subclass < ActiveRecord::Base

end

Subclass.new(hash, without_protection: true)
```

Gem versions are:

```
activemodel (3.2.13)
activerecord (3.2.13)
```

Why does this generate and argument error? [According to API Dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new/class), inititialize still takes two arguments as of 3.2.13

Comment: Can you confirm you are calling it with the parenthesis? `Subclass.new(hash, without_protection: true)`

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Yep. Using parenthesis

Comment: Are you sure the error is cause at `Subclass.new`? It may be occurring at some other place.

Comment: @sawa The code I've posted is what I'm running to generate this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like RubyGems is using the incorrect version of ActiveModel. From the error:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:180:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

No idea why, so posted another question (here)[Rubygems Loading Wrong Version of Gem